# How to change port number in jboss-7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am using jboss-7 and I want to change the port number from 8080 to 7001.  Which file do I need to change?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The file is `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`. Find `<socket-binding-group>` and `<socket-binding>` there.

**EDIT**

There's multiple ways to do this. The recommended way is to use the management console.
If JBoss AS runs on your local computer, open the URL `http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#socket-bindings` and edit the socket-bindings there. I tested it on Wildfly 8.1.0 Final, don't know if the URL is valid for other versions of JBoss AS.

Answer (score 28):

When starting use

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000 &
```

- for linux

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

- windows

```
here 1000 is the offset value. 8080 + 1000 = 9080 the application will start
```

Answer (score 3):

go to installation directory ....
Mine directory like that

```
C:\wildfly-10.0.0.CR5\standalone\configuration\
```

find `standalone.xml` file, open and change the http port `8080` inside

```
<socket-binding-group>
```

Here I change my port number 8080 to 3333

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:3333}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

standalone.bat

is using

standalone.conf.bat

Open in notepad

Add the last 2 lines (as seen below, aka the 2 "Alter Port Settings Offset" lines) (the first 3 lines should already be there...and provide the breadcrumb to where to place the 2 new lines that you need)

```
rem # Make Byteman classes visible in all module loaders
rem # This is necessary to inject Byteman rules into AS7 deployments
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

REM NEW LINE HERE Alter Port Settings Offset
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the socket-binding of http to your desire port number you want to use inside the socket-binding-group in your standalone.xml file of jboss.For example i am using 8090 as my port number.

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="8090"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to jboss directory exp -
jboss-7.0.0.CR1\jboss-7.0.0.CR1\standalone\configuration

open standalone.xml file 
then change port number according to you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse I open port-offset (that corrispondes to standalone.xml) and modify jboss.socket.binding.port-offset from 0 to 1000
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change the port for JBoss in local, when running multiple instances below are the steps.

1. In the JBoss folder, go to standalone.xml.
2. search for
3. change the "port-offset=${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0} to 100 like below
   port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}
4. Then when ran standalone.bat, then Jboss will run on port 10090

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij (Ultimate is required) Jboss/Wildfly configuration, you could easily edit port offset inside run configuration window.

[image: run configuration jboss port change]